# Need help fix 400 Bad Request for CodeIgniter project

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter-2, bad-request

In my codeigniter project, i have the following htaccess file to remove the index.php from URL

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|js|media|style|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

I am using the search form (using form helper). Since it is POST based, I have created a controller called "pre_search" to redirect it to search controller so that the POSTed data will be visible in URL and I can use it with URI helper's segment method.

So my pre_search controller

```
<?php

class Presearch extends CI_Controller {

    //just to make form POST data visible in URL string for search
    public function index() {
        redirect('search/' . $this->input->post('term'));
    }
}
```

And search controller does the real search. For the mean time I have allowed all the characters in URL for testing.

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = '';
```

My problem is now when I have percentage sign (%) in URL it shows bad request. I think it is the apache's response and codeigniter have nothing to do with it.

After some research I found that somebody suggested to fix that problem by modifying htaccess like this

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [B,L]
```

I have tried this method and it breaks everything.

Since % sign was not encoded, I tried to use also in my pre_search controller like this

```
redirect('search/' . urlencode($this->input->post('term')));
```

But didn't solve the problem.

So what is the best way to solve this? I know this is apache problem. I am just illustrating my codeigniter codes to clarify my intentions.

Thanks in advance

Deepak

Answer (score 0):

I do the same, these are my params and I also found this link it might help you with the htaccess http://www.dracos.co.uk/code/apache-rewrite-problem/

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('s', '','trim|min_length[3]|required|xss_clean');
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE):
    $this->session->set_flashdata('errorMsg', form_error('s'));
    redirect($this->session->userdata['redirectUrl']);
else:
    redirect(base_url() . $this->lang->line('link_search') . '/' . $this->functions->convertToUrl($this->functions->secureString($this->input->post('s', TRUE))));
endif;
```

My config values

```
 $config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%\.\:_\-ñ';
 $config['uri_protocol'] = 'PATH_INFO';
```

I convert the POST to legible url, changing characters to the ones permitted, and then I do the redirect.